# How to save a results of a sftp connection in a variable and don't display it in the screen in UNIX

Tags: shell, variables, unix, sftp

Hi I'm trying to save the SFTP connection result in a variable to print it later in another time, but I don't want it to do it in the execution time.

```
sftp -b ${SFTPCommands} $User@$IP 2>&1 > /dev/null
status=$?
if (($status != 0)); then
   print "$ConnectionTimeStamp - Attempt #$AttemptsCount - $IP - Connection Failed!"
   AttemptsCount=$(expr $AttemptsCount + 1)
fi
```

if it failed, the error it's printed at that time but i would like to do something like:

```
SFTPerror=$(sftp -b ${SFTPCommands} $User@$IP 2>&1 > /dev/null)
status=$?
if (($status != 0)); then
       print "$ConnectionTimeStamp - Attempt #$AttemptsCount - $IP - Connection Failed!"
       print "$SFTPerror"
       AttemptsCount=$(expr $AttemptsCount + 1)
fi
```

Comment: You could redirect to a tmp file instead of `/dev/null` and then use that to print the error when `status != 0`.. and then remove the file right after..

Comment: Thank you! this solve my issue.